# How to handle Permission errors when connecting with AWS s3 in Airflow 2.x?

Tags: python, airflow

I followed the number 2 instruction from [this manual](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html) to use `S3Hook`:

[image]

Note: I hide the credential info with `THIS_IS_CREDENTIAL`.

And here is the simple code to test:

```
from airflow.operators.python import task

@task
def load_to_s3():
    from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook

    s3_hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id="my_s3")
    s3_hook.load_string(
        string_data="ABC",
        key="year=2021/month=1/day=1/test.txt",
        bucket_name="my_bucket_in_s3",
    )


default_args = {
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    "schedule_interval": "@daily",
}
with DAG("my_test_dag2", default_args=default_args) as dag:
    load_to_s3()
```

Errors occured:

```
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,896] {base_aws.py:362} INFO - Airflow Connection: aws_conn_id=my_s3
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,905] {base_aws.py:173} INFO - No credentials retrieved from Connection
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,905] {base_aws.py:76} INFO - Retrieving region_name from Connection.extra_config['region_name']
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,905] {base_aws.py:78} INFO - Creating session with aws_access_key_id=None region_name=ap-northeast-1
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,913] {base_aws.py:151} INFO - role_arn is arn:aws:iam::THIS_IS_CREDENTIAL:role/airflow-v1
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,913] {base_aws.py:97} INFO - assume_role_method=None
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,930] {base_aws.py:182} INFO - Doing sts_client.assume_role to role_arn=arn:aws:iam::THIS_IS_CREDENTIAL:role/airflow-v1 (role_session_name=Airflow_my_s3)
[2021-05-27 09:58:26,932] {credentials.py:519} WARNING - Refreshing temporary credentials failed during mandatory refresh period.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 516, in _protected_refresh
    metadata = self._refresh_using()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 657, in fetch_credentials
    return self._get_cached_credentials()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 667, in _get_cached_credentials
    response = self._get_credentials()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 872, in _get_credentials
    kwargs = self._assume_role_kwargs()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 882, in _assume_role_kwargs
    identity_token = self._web_identity_token_loader()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 2152, in __call__
    with self._open(self._web_identity_token_path) as token_file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token'

...
```

It looks like airflow found out `role_arn=arn:aws:iam::THIS_IS_CREDENTIAL:role/airflow-v1` but
can't understand why the Airflow tries to access `/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token`. I'd like to solve it without something like `chmod 755 /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token` (I have no root privilege currently)

Answer (score -1):

, I think you don't need to specify the AWS Airflow role, so you can do it by adding the programmatic credentials, something like that :

[image: S3 connection]